# System.out.Println problems

Tags: java

This is written in Java.

This is a two class program (one testing) that checks a String for vowels and keeps a count of how many are present.

Everything seems to be working fine except for the `System.out.println()`s on the second class (for testing).

I have never come across this problem before, but I think it is only relative to the print lines themselves.

The print lines are at the bottom.

Here are the two classes:

```
/** Tests the sentence for the vowels
 * @ Jon Kosaka
 */

public class Sentence
{
    String sentence;

    public Sentence(String text)
    {
        sentence = text;
    }

    public boolean isPalindrome()
    {

        int low = 0;

        int high = sentence.length() -1;

        boolean match = true;

        while (low < high && match)
        {
            if (sentence.charAt(low) != sentence.charAt(high))
            {
                match = false;
            }

            low++;
            high--;
        }
        return match;
    }

    public String getSentence()
    {
        return sentence;
    }

    public void setSentence(String newText)
    {
        sentence = newText;
    }


    public int[] getVowelCounts()
    {

        final int A_INDEX = 0;
        final int E_INDEX = 0;
        final int I_INDEX = 0;
        final int O_INDEX = 0;
        final int U_INDEX = 0; 

        //              a  e  i  o  u
        int[] counts = {A_INDEX, E_INDEX, I_INDEX, O_INDEX, U_INDEX};
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
            if (sentence.charAt(0) == 'a')
                counts[0]++;
            if (sentence.charAt(0) == 'e')
                counts[1]++;
            if (sentence.charAt(0) == 'i')
                counts[2]++;
            if (sentence.charAt(0) == 'o')
                counts[3]++;
            if (sentence.charAt(0)  == 'u')
                counts[4]++;

        }
        return counts;
    }


}
```

Other class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
  An application to count the number of each individual vowel
  @ Jon Kosaka
 */

public class WorkingWithStrings
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //create a scanner
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        //get the input
        System.out.println("Enter a sentence and I will count each vowel: ");
        String input = console.nextLine();

        //Create a vowelCounter and call method to count the vowels
        Sentence sentence = new Sentence(input);
        int[] counts = sentence.getVowelCounts();
    }
    //display the results
    System.out.println("Vowel Count for the sentence: ");
    System.out.println("      " + sentence.getSentence());
    System.out.println("number of a: " + counts[Sentence.A_INDEX]);
    System.out.println("number of e: " + counts[Sentence.E_INDEX]);
    System.out.println("number of i: " + counts[Sentence.I_INDEX]);
    System.out.println("number of o: " + counts[Sentence.O_INDEX]);
    System.out.println("number of u: " + counts[Sentence.U_INDEX]);

}
```

Comment: is the closing `}` from the `main` method accidently missplaced - or is this a 1:1 copy of your code? And please describe what error you're getting, is it a compile error, or an exception during runtime?

Comment: @lwe this is my friend's code, and this is a 1:1 copy

Comment: And what's the problem? Please be more specific and don't make us guess.

Comment: @Thomas i shall post an ideone link

Comment: @tekknolagi As you can see these are compiler errors indicating something is wrong at that line or before. The other answers already showed you that those lines are not inside any method or initializer block and thus are invalid there.

Answer (score 2):

Some of your statements are outside of any method. This won't compile.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
   An application to count the number of each individual vowel
   @ Jon Kosaka
*/

public class WorkingWithStrings
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    //create a scanner
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    //get the input
    System.out.println("Enter a sentence and I will count each vowel: ");
    String input = console.nextLine();

    //Create a vowelCounter and call method to count the vowels
    Sentence sentence = new Sentence(input);
    int[] counts = sentence.getVowelCounts();
    //}  DELETED HERE
    //display the results
    System.out.println("Vowel Count for the sentence: ");
    System.out.println("      " + sentence.getSentence());
    System.out.println("number of a: " + counts[Sentence.A_INDEX]);
    System.out.println("number of e: " + counts[Sentence.E_INDEX]);
    System.out.println("number of i: " + counts[Sentence.I_INDEX]);
    System.out.println("number of o: " + counts[Sentence.O_INDEX]);
    System.out.println("number of u: " + counts[Sentence.U_INDEX]);
  } //ADDED HERE
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many bugs :)

1:

To find and increment vowel counts you have:

```
for (i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
 if (sentence.charAt(0) == 'a')
     counts[0]++;
 ...
```

which checks the character at index `0` in every iteration. So

```
if (sentence.charAt(0) == 'a')
```

should be

```
if (sentence.charAt(i) == 'a')
```

2:

You've misplaced a `}` in your `main` method, as a result some of the code is outside any function. Fix that.

3:

The constants `A_INDEX`, `B_INDEX`... are method local in one class and you are accessing them from another class. You need to make them static variables of the `Sentence` class. Also you've assigned all of them value `0`, Since they are used as the index in the array which hold vowel count. so you need:

```
static final int A_INDEX = 0;
static final int E_INDEX = 1;
static final int I_INDEX = 2;
static final int O_INDEX = 3;
static final int U_INDEX = 4;
```

4:

Change:

```
int[] counts = {A_INDEX, E_INDEX, I_INDEX, O_INDEX, U_INDEX};
```

to

```
int[] counts = {0,0,0,0,0};
```

[**Here is a working program**](http://ideone.com/6FFsk)

Comment: maybe add what @Udo answered as well to have a complete answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems with this:

1. Your System.out.println() is sitting outside your main function
2. Sentence.A_INDEX, etc, aren't static class variables, they're declared inside a member function

Answer (score 1):

You have to put System.out.print in `public static void main`

public class WorkingWithStrings
    {

```
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      //create a scanner
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

      //get the input
      System.out.println("Enter a sentence and I will count each vowel: ");
      String input = console.nextLine();

      //Create a vowelCounter and call method to count the vowels
      Sentence sentence = new Sentence(input);
      int[] counts = sentence.getVowelCounts();

//display the results
      System.out.println("Vowel Count for the sentence: ");
      System.out.println("      " + sentence.getSentence());
      System.out.println("number of a: " + counts[Sentence.A_INDEX]);
      System.out.println("number of e: " + counts[Sentence.E_INDEX]);
      System.out.println("number of i: " + counts[Sentence.I_INDEX]);
      System.out.println("number of o: " + counts[Sentence.O_INDEX]);
      System.out.println("number of u: " + counts[Sentence.U_INDEX]);
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact problem, here are some suspicions:

`counts[Sentence.A_INDEX]` etc. references a static field `A_INDEX` which doesn't exist in `Sentence`.
If it would exist as a static variable, all of those would still be initialized to 0 so `counts[Sentence.A_INDEX]` and  `counts[Sentence.E_INDEX]` would both be translated to `counts[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

there are few issues in your code i think this one is exactly right/correct code that you want.

```
 public class Sentence
{
   String sentence;

   public Sentence(String text)
   {
      sentence = text;
   }

   public boolean isPalindrome()
   {

      int low = 0;

      int high = sentence.length() -1;

      boolean match = true;

       while (low < high && match)
       {
          if (sentence.charAt(low) != sentence.charAt(high))
          {
             match = false;
          }

          low++;
          high--;
       }
       return match;
   }

   public String getSentence()
   {
      return sentence;
   }

   public void setSentence(String newText)
   {
      sentence = newText;
   }


   public int[] getVowelCounts()
   {

       final int A_INDEX = 0;
       final int E_INDEX = 0;
       final int I_INDEX = 0;
       final int O_INDEX = 0;
       final int U_INDEX = 0; 

//              a  e  i  o  u
int[] counts = {A_INDEX, E_INDEX, I_INDEX, O_INDEX, U_INDEX};
int i;
for (i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
 if (sentence.charAt(i) == 'a')
     counts[0]++;
 if (sentence.charAt(i) == 'e')
     counts[1]++;
 if (sentence.charAt(i) == 'i')
     counts[2]++;
 if (sentence.charAt(i) == 'o')
     counts[3]++;
 if (sentence.charAt(i)  == 'u')
     counts[4]++;

}
return counts;
   }


}




import java.util.Scanner;
/**
   An application to count the number of each individual vowel
   @ Jon Kosaka
*/

public class WorkingWithStrings
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      //create a scanner
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

      //get the input
      System.out.println("Enter a sentence and I will count each vowel: ");
      String input = console.nextLine();

      //Create a vowelCounter and call method to count the vowels
      Sentence sentence = new Sentence(input);
      int[] counts = sentence.getVowelCounts();
```

//display the results

```
      System.out.println("Vowel Count for the sentence: ");
      System.out.println("      " + sentence.getSentence());
      System.out.println("number of a: " + counts[0]);
      System.out.println("number of e: " + counts[1]);
      System.out.println("number of i: " + counts[2]);
      System.out.println("number of o: " + counts[3]);
      System.out.println("number of u: " + counts[4]);

  }

}
```